# What is wrong with this Python code? Why is it not editing the text file?

Tags: python

I am trying to create a code that will check if the user has done the quiz and if they have will put their score next to their previous score and if they haven't it will just add their name and score. 
This is the code:

```
if userclass=="1":
   with open("Class1scores.txt","a+",) as class1file:
        lines = class1file.readlines() # all lines are stored here
        for i,line in enumerate(lines):
            if username in lines:
               print("yes")
               lines[i] = lines[i].strip() + ":" + str(score) + "\n"
            else:
                print("nope")
                with open("Class1scores.txt","w",) as class1file:
                     class1file.write(str(username) + ":" + str(score))
                     class1file.write("\n")
        class1file.seek(0)
        for line in lines:
            class1file.write(line)

class1file.close()
```

This is the text file:

```
Humzah:10
Humzah:0
Jack:10
```

I want it to be like:

```
Humzah:0:10
Jack:10
```

It doesn't even print Yes nope so I know its something to do with that if statement but do not know what?
    enter code here

Comment: It should be `if username in line:`, not `if username in lines:`.  You want to check each line, not all of the lines as a whole.

Comment: its still not working sadly ; it has the same problem

Comment: I take it v1 was banned due to questions like http://stackoverflow.com/q/36228542/3001761?

Comment: I'm just really stressed out ok: I thought stack over flow would actually be a good community of people and I've asked plenty more of useful questions and either no one has answered or people have left sarcastic comments. I really need this programme to work so please stop  picking on a 14 year old boy and try to help me

Comment: Ok, So you want to convert file1 to file2?

Comment: just a wild guess...are you supposed to be comparing `userclass` to `"1"` or `1`

Comment: convert? I want to do everything in 1 file (Clas1scores) and check if a username is there if it is add the score to that line if it isn't then just add it to the last line

Comment: The file is empty or does not exist or `userclass` is not equal to `"1"`.

Comment: Help yourself - learn [ask] and [edit] the question accordingly.

Comment: The code in your question isn't a [mcve], but I guess your questions _are_ getting better. So I'll post you some code.

Answer (score 4):

Your file handling is a bit confused. The main problem is that you're repeatedly re-opening the file in write mode for each line that doesn't contain the desired `username`, clobbering its current content with the new stuff you write. And you're doing that while the file is already open in append mode, which is even more confusing. :)

I suggest a simpler approach: read the file into a list of lines, modify the list, then write the modified list.

Note that you should *not* `.close()` a file that you opened in a `with` statement: it will be closed automatically for you as soon as the `with` block is exited.

```
from __future__ import print_function

fname = "Class1scores.txt"

#username, score = "Humzah", 0
#username, score = "Jack", 10
username, score = "Humzah", 10


# Read current file data into a list of lines, 
# discarding the newline at the end of each line
try:
    with open(fname, "r") as f:
        lines = f.read().splitlines()
except IOError:
    #Create empty list if no file exists.
    #This isn't totally robust, since other IO errors may occur.
    lines = []

#Scan each line to see if contains the current `username`
for i, line in enumerate(lines):
    if line.startswith(username):
        print(username, "found on line", i)
        lines[i] += ":" + str(score)
        break
else:
    #Control only gets here if we don't `break` out of the `for` loop
    print(username, "not found; appending to list")
    lines.append(username + ":" + str(score))

#Save modified list
data = "\n".join(lines) + "\n"
with open(fname, "w") as f:
    f.write(data)
```